# laravel 5 routes where in group

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I wanna create url like this

http://example.com/url1/product/blabla
http://example.com/url2/product/aiueo

I can't achieve with this

```
Route::prefix('{page}')->name('the_url')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@page')
        ->name('index');

})->where('page', '(url1|url2)');
```

Or should I use the `where()` in every method inside the `{page}` prefix?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use it with group like this:

```
Route::group([
    'as' => 'the_url',
    'prefix' => '{page}', 
    'where' => [
        'page' => 'url1|url2'
    ],
], function () {
    // Group routes
});
```

Comment: thanks it solve my problem :)
although `'name'` should change to `'as'`

Comment: Good to hear! And yes, `name` was a mistake (changed it to `as` now)